Get blank PDF when generating privacy report using Xcode
Get blank PDF when generating privacy report using Xcode
Step follows:

Open your project in Xcode.

Choose Product > Archive. Xcode creates the archive and reveals it in the organizer.

Control-click the archive in the organizer and choose Generate Privacy Report.

Choose a location to save the privacy report.

Switch to Finder: Navigate to the location where you saved the privacy report, and double-click to open the report in Preview.


I can't see the content when I open the privacy report file. Could you help me resolve this issue?


Use the privacy report to better understand all of the data collected by your app

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/privacy_manifest_files/describing_data_use_in_privacy_manifests#4239187
The Privacy Report only includes the collected data types the app and it's SDK's collect and track. The descriptions of use of required reason API's information that is included in the manifests is never included in the privacy report.
So if you app, or the SDKs that it uses don't collect any data, your report could be empty.

If you added a privacy manifest to your project, make sure it is linked to your project’s target.
If you are talking about the pods and third party libraries your app depends on, try to embed their privacy bundles to your project’s target.
Then generate a new archive and see if it solves your issue.
